# Doing left outer join on multiple data frames in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am newbie in Spark. I trying to achieve below use case using scala.

```
-DataFrame 1

| col A | col B |
-----------------
|  1    | a     |
|  2    | a     |
|  3    | a     |

-DataFrame 2

| col A | col B |
-----------------
|  1    | b     |
|  3    | b     |

-DataFrame 3

| col A | col B |
-----------------
|  2    | c     |
|  3    | c     |
```

Final Output frame should be

```
| col A | col B |
-----------------
|  1    | a,b   |
|  2    | a,c   |
|  3    | a,b,c |
```

Number of frames are not limited to 3 , it can be any number less than 100.So I am using for each in which I am printing each of the data frame.

Can some one please help me how I can create final data frame in which I can have output in above format with N data frames.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this question today. I suggest that you use python to solve it. It's easier to write than scala. Here are they:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws

d1=sc.parallelize([(1, "a"), (2, "a"), (3,"a")]).toDF().toDF("Col_A","Col_B")

d2=sc.parallelize([(1, "b"), (2, "b")]).toDF().toDF("Col_A", "Col_B")

d3=sc.parallelize([(2, "c"), (3, "c")]).toDF().toDF("Col_A", "Col_B")

d4=d1.join(d2,'Col_A','left').join(d3,'Col_A','left').select(d1.Col_A.alias("col A"),concat_ws(',',d1.Col_B,d2.Col_B,d3.Col_B).alias("col B"))

df4.show()

+-----+-----+

|col A|col B|

+-----+-----+

|    1
|  a,b|

|    2
|a,b,c|

|    3
|  a,c|

+-----+-----+
```

You see the result!

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foldLeft` to iteratively merge data with outer join

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = Seq((1, "a"), (2, "a"), (3, "a")).toDF("Col A", "Col B")
val df2 = Seq((1, "b"), (2, "b")).toDF("Col A", "Col B")
val df3 = Seq((2, "c"), (3, "c")).toDF("Col A", "Col B")

val dfs = Seq(df2, df3)
val bs = (0 to dfs.size).map(i => s"Col B $i")

dfs.foldLeft(df1)(
  (acc, df) => acc.join(df, Seq("Col A"), "fullouter")
).toDF("Col A" +: bs: _*).select($"Col A", array(bs map col: _*)).map {
  case Row(a: Int, bs: Seq[_]) => 
    // Drop nulls and concat
    (a, bs.filter(_ != null).map(_.toString).mkString(","))
}.toDF("Col A", "Col B").show

// +-----+-----+ 
// |Col A|Col B|
// +-----+-----+
// |    1|  a,b|
// |    3|  a,c|
// |    2|a,b,c|
// +-----+-----+
```

but if you really think

> it can be any number less than 100

then it is just unrealistic. `join` is the most expensive operation in Spark, and even with all the optimizer improvements, it is just not gonna work.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help.